# what is P(X|X), if it has any meaning

Tags: probability, self-study

Easy question.

What is $P(X|X)$, if it means anything?

I guess it is $P(X|X)=1$, but am not sure.

It came up for me while trying different ways to prove something else.

Comment: $P(X|X)=\frac{P(X\cap X)}{P(X)}=\frac{P(X)}{P(X)}=1$

Comment: It depends what you symbolize with $X$ and what with $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X \in \mathcal{F}$ is an outcome from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. In that case, yes: $P(X|X) = 1$. Because per definition

$$P(X|X) = \frac{P(X \cap X)}{P(X)} = \frac{P(X)}{P(X)} = 1$$

Comment: Note that this assumes $P(X) \ne 0$